# drop tags in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

Given I have strings how can I drop all the tags. For example:

```
string = hello<tag1>there</tag1> I <tag2> want to </tag2> strip <tag3>all </tag3>these tags
>>>> hello there I want to strip all these tags
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text attribute is the most straightforward one, but it just copies the text nodes verbatim, thus you get

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""hello<tag1>there</tag1> I <tag2> want to </tag2> strip <tag3>all </tag3>these tags""")
>>> soup.text
u'hellothere I  want to  strip all these tags'
```

You can squeeze all whitespace with

```
>>> ' '.join(soup.text.split())
u'hellothere I want to strip all these tags'
```

---

Now, the space missing between `'hello'` and `'there`' is a tricky one because if the `<tag1>` were `<b>` then it would be rendered by user agents as hello**there**, without any intervening space; one needs to parse CSS to know which elements are supposed to be inline and  which ones not.

However if we allow each non-text node (and closing tags) be replaced by space, a crude one would be to search all text nodes separately with `soup.findChildren`, split each of them separately, merge these lists with `itertools.chain` and then `join` them all together with a single space as separator:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> words = chain(*(i.split() for i in soup.findChildren(text=True)))
>>> ' '.join(words)
u'hello there I want to strip all these tags'
```

Comment: thanks, but how to deal with the irregular spacings??